# autoheader creates VERSION macro conflicting to other variable defined in other header file

Tags: macros, version, conflict, autoconf

My configure.ac file has line as below

```
AC_INIT([myApp], [1.2.3], [dev@company.com])
```

then autoheader/configure will create `config.in` in which we will have 2 macros as below,

```
/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2.3"

/* Version number of package */
#define VERSION "1.2.3"
```

I also need build sqlite in the same project and sqlite header file also defined variable `VERSION`, then I got error like below

```
../../config.h:117:17: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

 #define VERSION "1.2.3"
                 ^ ../../SQLiteCpp/include/SQLiteCpp/Database.h:35:21:note: in expansion of macro ‘VERSION’

 extern const char*  VERSION;        ///< SQLITE_VERSION string from the sqlite3.h used at compile time
```

I have to manually modify config.in to comment out `VERSION` macro every time to let build continue. My questions are:

1. Why 2 macros created in `config.h`, `PACKAGE_VERSION` and `VERSION` looks the same, what is the difference?
2. How to resolve this `VERSION` macro/variable conflicting issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why both `VERSION` and `PACKAGE_VERSION`? Probably backwards compatibility.

How to avoid defining `VERSION`? The `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` documentation in the `Automake` info page ends with a paragraph dealing exactly with how to avoid `PACKAGE` and `VERSION` being `AC_DEFINE`d:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([... no-define ...])
```